# programmatically reformatting a .Rnw to break lines at 80 characters

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

I'm writing my thesis in RStudio with knitr and want to go back and reformat my .Rnw files so that no line exceeds 80 characters.

I've noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299699/reformatting-text-or-better-latex-in-80-colums-in-scite) for scite but I'm not sure how to make this work in my situation.

Are there are `R` tools (or command line tools) to do this kind of job?

Comment: wouldn't doing that programmatically insert line breaks where they might break your code or mess things up? in the middle of a variable name or character string for instance?

Comment: Technically, a robust solution should find the closest bit of white space to the 80 character mark and break from there. Either way, breaking the code is a risk I'm willing to take.

Comment: "if all you have is a hammer, ..." here is a solution using a text editor http://superuser.com/questions/464456/sublime-text-2-insert-breaks-to-match-current-wrapping

Comment: You might find this paper interesting, too http://bloodjournal.hematologylibrary.org/content/103/2/746.full

Comment: I don't think my use of robust was gratuitous but I can see where you're coming from. ;-)

Comment: have you tried running the R source through [formatR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formatR)? There is an option for line char length limit: `tidy.source(source="clipboard", width.cutoff=80)`

Comment: it doesn't need to be on the clipboard, too :-) not sure it will do anything for non-R source code, tho.

Comment: I just came across the formatR package and came back here to suggest it as well @StevieP